# python why one function defined in a class cant be called inside another function in same class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Why below code doesn't work?

i am trying to call a zz() method and it works but when i try to call the ff() method it didn't worked it says zz not defined, while i am trying to call the zz inside the ff, and both are independent methods, is there's any ways of calling two independent method without nesting them in one many method?

CODE:

```
class A(object):
    def zz(self):
        return"zz is working"

    def ff(self):
        zz(self)
        return "zz and ff both ran"
b=A()
print(b.ff())
```

Error:
  File "C:\Users\baggaa\AppData\Local\atom\WAP\WAP\Temp.py", line 3, in ff
    zz()
NameError: name 'zz' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You should call self.zz()

In this case self is link to your class instance.